# How to apply the function substr to each element of a string

Tags: r, string, substr

I have this string of words

```
string<-c("chair-desk-tree-table-computer-mousse")
```

I want to retrieve the first three characters of each word and store them in an object like that:

```
newstring==> [1] "cha-des-tre-tab-com-mou"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> newstring <- substring( strsplit(string, "-")[[1]], 1, 3)
> newstring <- paste0(newstring, collapse = "-")
> newstring
[1] "cha-des-tre-tab-com-mou"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `gsub` with a regex lookaround to match one or more lower case letters that precede 3 lower case letters

```
gsub("(?<=\\b[a-z]{3})[a-z]+", "", string, perl = TRUE)
[1] "cha-des-tre-tab-com-mou"
```

Using the edited string

```
> string <- c(string, "K29-E665-I1190")
> gsub("(?<=\\b[[:alnum:]]{3})[[:alnum:]]+", "", string, perl = TRUE)
[1] "cha-des-tre-tab-com-mou" "K29-E66-I11"
```

Comment: In fact my real string is not only made of letters, but also numbers and capital letters

Comment: @SeydouGORO then just change it to `[A-Za-z]` instead of `[a-z]`

Comment: thank you again but ```[A-Za-z]``` seem to not take into account numbers

Comment: @SeydouGORO sorry, i don't know about your actual case.  If there are numbers you need `[[:alnum:]]` instead of `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: Sorry for not being precise, here is a part of my real string: ```K29-E665-I1190```

Comment: @SeydouGORO is the updated output you wanted